# fmincon error occurs without details in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I followed the instructions, but what I only can get is "error in (filename)" without any additional details. Could you tell me which part made an error?

```
clear;clc;lb = [0,0]; 
ub = [1,1]; 
A = [1 1]; 
B = [1]; 
Aeq = []; 
Beq = []; 
x0=[0.5, 0.5]; 
f=@(x)(200*x(1)-37)^2+(200*x(2)-83)^2+(200*x(1)+200*x(2)-122)^2+(400*x(1)-82)^2+(400*x(2)-157)^2+(400*x(1)+400*x(2)-250)^2; 
x = fmincon(f,x0,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub)
```

Comment: What happens when you clear your workspace, and copy paste the code in? Do you have some function/script on that path with a name of one of the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is work fine, and this is the result:
x =

```
    0.2090    0.4050
```

you needs to save your script file and add the folder contain your file to matlab "Add to path".

[image]